# SUMIFS statement works until a numeric field in criteria is applied, then it fails

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

I have a sumif statement that uses 11 criterias.  It works with all criterias that have text in them, but it fails to work when I add a field that has blanks and/or numbers in it.  I can't figure out how to overcome this problem and would like some help.  Here is my code:

```
Dim GS As Worksheet
Set GS = Worksheets("Grant Spreadsheet")

Dim LastRow As Long

With GS
    LastRow = GS.Range("W1000").End(xlUp).Row
    Me.TGATxtBx.Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("w2:w" & LastRow),_ 
    .Range("e2:e" & LastRow), "*" & Me.GrantNameCmboBx.Value & "*",_
    .Range("n2:n" & LastRow), "*" & Me.GrantAgencyCmboBx.Value & "*",_ 
    .Range("o2:o" & LastRow), "*" & Me.GrantDeptCmboBx.Value & "*",_ 
    .Range("p2:p" & LastRow), "*" & Me.ProgramCmboBx.Value & "*",_ 
    .Range("d2:d" & LastRow), "*" & Me.ProjTypeCmboBx.Value & "*",_ 
    .Range("r2:r" & LastRow), "*" & Me.CatalogNoCmboBx.Value & "*",_ 
    .Range("q2:q" & LastRow), "*" & Me.PassthroughCmboBx.Value & "*",_
    .Range("s2:s" & LastRow), "*" & Me.GrantIDCmboBx.Value & "*",_ 
    .Range("h2:h" & LastRow), "*" & Me.FundNoCmboBx.Value & "*"_
    .Range("i2:i" & LastRow), "*" & Me.OrgTxtBx.Value & "*",_
    .Range("k2:k" & LastRow), "*" & Me.AccountTxtBx.Value & "*")
```

Me.PassthroughCmboBx.Value has blanks and the three fields after that have numbers.  If I move things around and bring these fields in earlier between the criterias that do work, it fails.  I could really use your help.

Comment: `fails to work` does that mean it throws an error, or it returns the wrong value?

Comment: just a note by using wildcards and `&` you are forcing numbers into strings.  SUMIFS will not find strings inside numbers.

Comment: It processes, but instead of getting the value I expect, I get a zero.

Comment: Your comment about using wildcards and & are the problem, but I need to be able to type part of the criteria range into the range or leave the range blank to get the correct sum.  Any suggestions on how to force these fields into text format?  I've tried everything in my wheelhouse of knowledge.

Comment: I just figured out exactly what the problem is.  The code looks for the first blank row to find the end of the table.  Then the sumifs formula looks in each column, and if a cell has a blank, it zeros everything out.  So the data cannot have any blanks in it.  The only option I can think of is to force every cell in the data range to populate with something.  If someone else has another option, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: My solution was to create a process that filled in each blank field in the data rows with "FALSE". Once I did this, everything worked fine because there were no more blanks in the data rows.  Very similar to using the NZ (forces blanks to zero) in Microsoft Access.  I hope this helps others having the same issue.